# Making simple BASH Shell script that takes two arguments, checks them, then copies the first (file) argument to the second (directory) argument

Tags: shell-script

I have started a few days ago learning how to make scripts in shell. How can I make script thaht takes two arguments ( file name and some directory), if arguments are bad I want to make error alert and if they are correct I want to copy file in given directory?
so far I made this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d $1 ] ; then
 ???
 done
else
 echo $1 NOT DIRECTORY
 exit 1
fi
```

And separate I made a part for checking a file. How to put this together ?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
 echo "Use- $0 file"
 exit 1
fi
if [ -f $1 ]
then
 echo "$1 There is no file with that name"
else
 echo "$1 There is no file with that name"
fi
```

I am new to bash script so I would like to get some help.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried something so far? Share your attempts with us.

Comment: Have a look at [GreyCat and Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), and make a habit of checking your scripts using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) (also available as standalone tool in many Linux distributions).

Comment: you could have a look [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php) - this is a lession about parameters to shell scripts - also have a look at the other lessions, there may be other information you need.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity First thanks on welcome!  So far I have done the part that takes name of directory, and if it is not irectory I have appropriate feedback . I have edited my post. In part ?? I do not know how to take and check file name and make copyS

Comment: You can just nest the second `if` construct into the first branch of your first `if` (note that the `done` there is wrong; this only applies to `for` loops). And you would check for `$# -ne 2` to ensure two arguments are supplied, then use `$2` in the file check. Google for "positional parameters" in order to learn more.

Comment: @AdminBee yea just like every other language there is if - ele construction. But have a huge trouble by making this one works. Also hard time to make sucess copy

Comment: That's why I recommended shellcheck ... As for the "copy" part: `cp "$2" "$1"` assuming `$1` is the target directory and `$2` the file? If that doesn't work, please specify the error you get ...

Comment: Another thing that may help is to put your script into https://shellcheck.net/ every so often. It will identify errors and suspect code constructs, which in turn should help you improve your code quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tructure like this:

- First check the number of arguments is right, in this case 2

  ```
  if arguments not 2
    message "Not enough arguments" and exit
  ```
- Check that arguments are valid file and directory.

  ```
  if argument1 not a file
    message "Not af file" and exit

  if argument2 not a directory
    echo "Not a directory" and exit
  ```
- If both arguments are correct, perform the copy:

  ```
  message "Copying file"
  copy file to directory
  ```

Remember to exit in case of error, so the script doesn't keep running.

You can also use one liners instead of the if's:

```
[[ ! -f "$1" ]] && echo "Not a file" && exit
```

Comment: In this case you have two conditions, file *and* directory, so your message could be "bad file *or* directory" and exit.

Comment: Okay, great! So the rest is ok ?

Comment: Yes, it seems so :)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add the final code to the question, [edit] it, so everyone else can evaluate it.